# getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Accessing Object in SubView

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access, nsobject

Maybe a very basic problem, but i don't get it ...

I've written my own class for having Data as an Object in my iPhone app. The class is of Type NSObject. The Class has several NSString propertys and also three objects of other classes.

```
@interface vcardItem : NSObject {
vCardNitem *PersonName;
NSString *Phone;
NSString *PhotoURL;
vCardTELitem *PhoneData;
NSString *URL;
NSString *eMail;
vCardADRItem *Address;
NSString *Company;
NSString *Role;
int initialised;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) vCardNitem *PersonName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Phone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *PhotoURL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) vCardTELitem *PhoneData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *URL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *eMail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) vCardADRItem *Address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Company;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Role;
@property int initialised;

-(id)initEmpty;
-(id)initWithPayload:(NSString *)payload;
-(void)sendToAddressBook;
-(void)debugVCard;
-(NSString *)getFirstName;
@end
```

I'm creating an object of vcardItem in a function call within my viewcontroller. The Data is filled and accessible. The function initWithPayload is called and all propertys are set.

Then i open another view for showing Details and call the function setVCard with my vcardItem Object (which is still completeley accessible):

```
VCardViewController *aVCardViewController = [[VCardViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:aVCardViewController animated:YES];
[aVCardViewController setVCard:aVCard];
```

within the VCardViewController then, only the NSString propertys are accesible. As soon as i stry to access propertys of VCardNItem, vCardADRitem or vCardTELitem, i get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error.

Looks like the Objects within the vcardItem Object are not available !?

I've set the NSZombie... thing, my vcardItem Object is still living (No "Zombie"), but i cannot access the data.

any Idea? I'm a little bit stucked here....

Comment: Try as following,    VCardViewController *aVCardViewController = [[VCardViewController alloc] init];
[aVCardViewController setVCard:aVCard];                        [self presentModalViewController:aVCardViewController animated:YES];

Comment: Is just a convention but, in cocoa/cocoa-touch you write class names starting with a capital or capitals (usually taken from the correspondent framework) and variables names won't start with capitals. Your are doing it the other way around

Comment: @satya: If i switch the two statements, the result is, that no data is available in aVCardViewController.

Comment: I cannot understand why this happens. I now have changed the viewController. With "initWithPayload:(NSString *)payload" the viewController creates an object of vCardItem. The Object is accessible during viewDidLoad, all Data is displayed correctly within the view. Then i have a Button connected in IB to an IBAction. If i tap the button, i still get an EXC_BAD_ACCES within the IBAction, if i try to access the data. If i check the object within Debugger, the object still lives, no Zombie-Entrys there.

Comment: @MadMaxApp: switch the two statements and put nslog before the setVcard statement and print the aVcard object. and print same thing after setting. check whether it is printing correct values.

Comment: ok. If i NSLog the vcardItem Object aVCard, i see in Console "<vCardItem>". I can read all data thats defined within the class vCardItem itself in my object. If i NSLog the vCardNitem Object, which lies within the vCardItem "aVCard", is see in Console "<vCardNitem: 0x190b80>", which is also correct. If i NSLog the instance-variable "Firstname" with aVCard.PersonName.Firstname, i get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error again. I've set a breakpoint to watch the instance-Variable in Debugger. The instance-variable "FirstName" is of Type NSSting...

Comment: Did some code review and after building it in Xcode 4 against iOS 5 all is fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Review did the job, after building in Xcode 4 against iOS 5 all is fine!